# VS Code emmet classname autocomplete for Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, autocomplete, emmet

is there a way to change emmet autocomplete
from `className=""`   to `className={styles.}`
if yes how and if no, is there a way to create a custom autocomplete which works.
I tried several times without success and if you could help me, it would be a huge help.

Answer (score 1):

This feature will be available soon as a part of Attribute override feature: https://github.com/emmetio/py-emmet/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#attributes-override

Currently, it’s available in Sublime Text editor

Comment: Thank you for the information. Is there any info about when will this be available?